# Proof for existence of a common tangent

Tags: geometry, circles

Can we prove that two circles touching each other always have a common tangent at the same point without using the fact that the point of contact and the centres of the circles are collinear. When I did it used the factband it was pretty easy  but in proving this fact i need to prove that the ccommon tangent exists.
Proof of any result would help.

Comment: Do you need a proof using synthetic geometry?

Comment: Yes. But I will appreciate one using coordinate geometry too.